# Tenses in the sentence

Tags: past-tense

"On occasion **he had even been entrusted** with the rectification of ‘The Times’ leading articles, which **were written** entirely in Newspeak."

Why can't we say: "he was entrusted"?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in one of the responses to the question:
[Was vs had been](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164870/was-vs-had-been)

'Had been' means he might still be entrusted, but definately was at the time being referred to. 'Was' means he no longer is entrusted now.

Comment: I think you've got that the wrong way around. When I pass my test, I _was_ entrusted with my driver's license, and I still have it...