# What is the difference between two sentences?

Tags: past-tense

1)When the phone rang,I had been washing the dishes
2)when the phone rang,I was washing the dishes

Comment: I think this answer will solve your doubts https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164870/was-vs-had-been

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was vs had been](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164870/was-vs-had-been)

Comment: Sorry, Akul sharma and that will always depend on the context. In this case, what happened before or after, that mattered?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) When the phone rang, **I had been** washing the dishes

You washed the dishes, then stopped, then the phone rang.

> The PAST PERFECT PROGRESSIVE TENSE indicates a continuous action that
>   was completed at some point in the past. This tense is formed with the
>   modal "HAD" plus "BEEN," plus the present participle of the verb (with
>   an -ing ending): "I had been working in the garden all morning."

[Past Perfect Progressive tense](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect_progressive.htm)

> 2) when the phone **rang**, I **was washing** the dishes

You washed the dishes, while you were doing that, the phone rang.

We often use the past continuous and the past simple tense together to describe an action interrupted by an event. When this happens, the past continuous describes a longer, ‘background’ action or situation and the past simple describes the action or events.

> I was playing a computer game when the doorbell rang.

[Past Continuous and Past Simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/beginner-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple)

Comment: Don't you think had been+present participle is used for representing the ongoing actions in past

Comment: @Akul sharma - _"had been+present participle is used for representing the ongoing actions in past"_  Maybe you are thinking of 'have been' - the present perfect progressive tense which describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future.

Comment: Let's just take an example:Her friends had been thinking of calling the police when she walked in..what you will say now?

Comment: I will say the same. Had been thinking says the action was complete when she walked in.. Were thinking says it was still happening when she walked in.